# One to one relationship field causes a NullReferenceException on the razor details page (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

Am trying to display some fields on the Details page but the fields which have relationships don't show, they cause a **NullReferenceException**.

Below is my Student model :

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Nationality")]
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion")]
        public string Religion { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Medical Condition")]
        public string MedicalCondition { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Deceased")]
        public string Deceased { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Home Address")]
        public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Country Of Residence")]
        public string CountryOfResidence { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public virtual Parents Parents { get; set; }
        public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
        public virtual Guardian Guardian { get; set; }
        public virtual Siblings Siblings { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, Education model, this is the one with a **One-to-One** relationship.

```
public class Education
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Education Level")]
        public string EducationLevel { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="School")]
        public string School { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Address of School")]
        public string AddressOfSchool { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Head Teacher")]
        public string HeadTeacher { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Telephone")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public  virtual Student Student { get; set; }


        public long? StudentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then this is how am trying to Display some of the Attributes in a Razor page `Detail.cshtml`:

```
@model Student

<h2>Student Details</h2>
<p>@Model.Id</p>
<p>@Model.FirstName</p>
<p>@Model.MiddleName</p>
<p>@Model.LastName</p>
<p>@Model.Nationality</p>
<p>@Model.Gender</p>
<p>@Model.Religion</p>
<p>@Model.MedicalCondition</p>
<p>@Model.Deceased</p>
<p>@Model.HomeAddress</p>
<p>@Model.CountryOfResidence</p>
<p>@Model.City</p>
<p>@Model.DateOfBirth</p>
<p>@Model.Education.Telephone</p>
```

But this `<p>@Model.Education.Telephone</p>`, is the one which causes a NullReferenceException.

Furthermore, This is my **Detail** action in my controller.

```
  public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var pet = _studentRepository.GetSingleStudent(id);
            return View(pet);
        }
```

Then, the **RepositoryClass** ,

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public StudentRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public Student GetSingleStudent(int id)
        {

            var student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
            return student;
        }}
```

With all the information provided, what could be the best way to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply just include the class model in your query in the `GetSingleStudent()`.

Like

```
 public Student GetSingleStudent(int id)
        {

            var student = _context.Students
                .Include(e=>e.Education)
                .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
            return student;
        }
```

This will work for you.

For further more information check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976200/10381236)

**Good Luck.**

Answer (score 1):

Is lazy loading enabled?  Is the Education relationship loading along with the Student?  You may have to use an explicit .Include:

```
 var student = _context.Students
        .Include(x=>x.Education)
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```